# How to make text visible again on hover after a CSS animation?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to coding and I am trying to create a website for fun. I've only started learning so I don't know much, and maybe this is not the way to do it?

I have a class="txt1" that has an animation applied to it which fades the text away. However, I want the text to be visible again only when I hover over it once the animation is over. I've attached the code below

```
.txt1{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 20vw;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    margin-right: 15vw;

    font-size: 1.2em;
    
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fade-in-txt1 10s ease-in .5s forwards;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.txt1:hover{
    animation-play-state: paused !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;

}

@keyframes fade-in-txt1{
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    40% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity: 1;}
    85% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home-page-cs.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bck-img">
        <p class="txt1">Hello.</p>
    </div>
        <p class="home-text">You have come Home</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The animation plays fine, but nothing happens when I hover over where the text originally was.

Comment: Your code works fine (with a div class="txt1") so there must be something odd in your HTML. Please add that and create a runnable snippet and check that it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the HTML code

Comment: Your code works OK for me - the text shows when I hover over where it was showing during the animation. Please could you make your code into a runnable snippet and test that it shows the problem for you. What browser/OS are you on? I find it works on Edge/Windows10.

Comment: Oh, actually I have another snippet of code that overlaid a pseudo-element over the text. Which is why the hover didn't work. it works now. Thanks for replying though.